# Функции ввода/вывода с помощью вариативных шаблонов

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Как правильно реализовать функции `read`, `print` с помощью **вариативных шаблонов**?

```
read(a1, a2, ..., an); // тоже, что и cin >> a1 >> a2 >> ... >> an;
print(a1, a2, ..., an); // тоже, что и cout << a1 << " " << a2 << " " << ... << " " << an;
```

Comment: Что Вы вкладываете в понятие `правильно`?

Comment: @alexolut, вот, например, меня мучает вопрос как правильно записывать аргументы для таких функций `T... args`, `T&... args` или `T&&... args`.

Comment: Это уже может быть отдельным вопросом, никак не связанным с использованием ввода/вывода и вариативными шаблонами в том числе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename... T>
void print(const T&... args)
{
    int unused[] = { (std::cout << args, 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(unused);
}

template<typename... T>
void read(T&... args)
{
    int unused[] = { (std::cin >> args, 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(unused);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::string s;
    double d;
    read(i, s, d);
    print(i, s, d);
}
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XwQAXjJSQ6WqN28N)</kbd>

Comment: А что делает вот эта строка `int unused[] = { (std::cout << args, 0)... };`? Как оно вообще работает?

Comment: @Flowneee правая часть разворачивается в список инициализации и этим значением инициализируется массив. Как побочный эффект выполняются нужные нам действия, в данном случае - вывод в поток.

Comment: `static_cast<void>(unused);` а в чем смысл этой строки? Вроде как и без нее работает.

Comment: @Flowneee смысл этой строки - подавление предупреждения о неиспользуемом фактически массиве. Собственно, неспроста он назван `unused` :)

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы `print` выводила свои аргументы через пробел (или с другим заданным, например глобально, разделителем)?

Comment: @pank очевидно, добавить вывод пробела `<< " "` после `args`.

Comment: @alexolut, да, но после вывода последнего аргумента этот пробел не нужен.

Comment: @pank обычно на такие ситуации кладут болт, т.е. ничего плохого в лишнем разделителе после последнего элемента нет. Даже при инициализации массивов или определении `enum` допускается запятая в конце. Но если уж очень мешает, то надо просто обрабатывать последнюю итерацию особенным образом. В случае с текущим вопросом - можно задать терминальную версию с одним аргументом (для рекурсивного подхода), где разделитель выводится не будет. Или - выводить в промежуточный строковый поток, а дальше убирать финальный разделитесь уже из полученной строки при последующем выводе в `std::cout`.

Comment: @alexolut, уже сам разобрался: http://ideone.com/lEq6LR

Comment: @alexolut, есть какая-нибудь существенная разница между вашим кодом и кодом участника yrHeTaTeJlb?

Comment: @pank смотря что считать существенным. Но если не учитывать того, что мой был опубликован чуть раньше, то можно упомянуть отсутствие в объектном файле функций с пустым списком параметров.

Answer (score 4):

Немного рекурсии

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void read(){}

template<class Arg, class ...Args>
void read(Arg &arg, Args &...args){
    std::cin >> arg;
    read(args...);
}

void print(){}

template<class Arg, class ...Args>
void print(const Arg &arg, const Args &...args){
    std::cout << arg;
    print(args...);
}


int main(){
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string s;

    read(i, d, s);
    print(s, i, d);
}
```